# Вложенный запрос SQL в ORM

Tags: sql, kohana, orm, kohana-3

Как реализовать подобный запрос через ORM в kohana

```sql
select popular.name, popular.kol
from(
  select goods.name as name, sum(goods_incomes.goods_amount) as kol 
  from goods_incomes inner join goods on goods.id = goods_incomes.goods_id 
  where incomes.client_id = 4 GROUP 
  BY goods.name order by name) as popular
  where popular.kol > 20
```

Comment: Конкретизируй о какой ORM идет речь. Их сотни.

Comment: Или что за фреймворк?

Comment: делается на  Kohana

Comment: @DarkVss ну так поправь свой вопрос чтобы было это было ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если сильно хочется ОРМ:

- запрос -

  SELECT t1.id, (

  SELECT COUNT( * ) 
  FROM reestr_1 t2
  WHERE t1.id >= t2.id
  ) AS count, t1.title, t1.address, t1.phones
  FROM reestr_1 t1
- решение -

  $count_sql = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reestr t2 WHERE reestr.id >= t2.id) as count';
   ORM::factory('reestr')
      ->select('id', DB::expr($count_sql), 'title', 'address', 'phones')
      ->find_all();
- вот как я решал свою проблему.